# excel VBA - refurn variable length array from function

Tags: vba, excel

I want to emulate the results of the builtin "text-to-fields" in a UDF function. 
I need to do this because my original data comes from a web query, and I need to use the results on a separate page and plot those results. 
For plotting, I need missing values to parse to empty cells, since that is the only option for excel graphs to show missing values as gaps.

You cannot do that with the builtin, because of two limitations;

1) It cannot target the parsed fields onto another sheet.

2) Trying to copy the data values to the destination sheet to parse them there fails, because text-to-fields parses the referencing expression, instead of the value it references.

3) I cannot parse on the original data sheet, and then copy the parsed fields to the target sheet, because no expression can copy an empty cell, it gets converted into a zero value. (after all, an expression resulting in an empty cell would erase itself!)

So I need a DIY field parser, and in any case using a formula is better for my overall needs than having to macro-ize the builtin function (even if it would work).

My fields look like this:

```
   calm
    S 10
    S 10 G 20
```

And I want them to parse just as a text-to-fields would, which would give numerics for numbers, strings for text, and **empty** for missing fields (i.e. shorter readings.)

So I used this code;

```
Function Explode(texte As String, Optional ByVal delimiter As String = " ") _
            As String()
'    mimic the text-to-fields,
'    but allow inter-sheet references
    Explode = Split(texte, delimiter)
End Function
```

But to use it, I have to pre-define the function calling cell as part of an array, which is fixed size, and I don't know how to have this return a variable number of parsed fields into a fixed size array. What I want from the sample data above is:

[image]

But what I get instead is:

[image]

Note that empty cells must be empty - not just look empty (not "" strings).

**Edit**: 
I suspect that I may have to instead create a *sub* which sets the values of the parsed fields and clears the remainder of cells for missing fields (I always have a maximum of four fields) instead of returning them, but am not very VBA proficient. For example, something that gets two cell references, one for the source reference, another for the target list of parsed fields. Then call that from a *function* which I can embed in the sheet. Side-effect based programming...

Comment: Difficult to see how you'd do this line-by-line using a UDF, when some lines are shorter than others: any given line by itself would need to know how many fields it was "supposed" to have.  You'd almost need to pass in an additional parameter to determine how many values should be in the output.

Comment: Can you provide some sample data or even better a downloadable test stub?

Comment: You can't return Empty from a function, so I'm afraid your UDF won't ever do what you want. You can simply resize your output array using `Application.Caller.Count` for what that's worth.

Comment: @Rory - I realize I can't return empty, but wondered if I could return a shorter array, and thus just leave the remaining cells in the target empty (would clear them before).

Comment: @Tim - If I understood yur comment, the input text determines the number of fields to return, no need for an explicit parameter to specify.

Comment: Nope - if you put the formula into the cells, which you need to, they have to return something. For a chart #N/A values are often a good option.

Comment: @Rory - Thanks, but I think that graphs will only show gaps for missing values that are empty cells. If it would do for #NA, this would be easy and I won't need VBA as I can just use an expression for he splitting (this is what I started with). The whole problem is getting gaps for missing data points, when expressions or functions cannot generate empty cells, which is the only thing graphs will show as gaps (if I understand correctly).

Comment: It depends on the chart type and/or whether the errors are interspersed within actual data. In any event a formula solution is not going to give you empty cells.

Comment: @Rory - yep. Interspersed.

Answer (score 0):

You could make your function return a fixed array size using Redim Preserve.

> {=Explode($A$1,50,",")}

```
Function Explode(texte As String, ArraySize As Integer, Optional ByVal delimiter As String = " ") _
            As String()
    Explode = Split(texte, delimiter)
    ReDim Preserve Explode(ArraySize- 1)
End Function
```